# How to load URL on safari through COCOA APP

Tags: xcode, cocoa, safari

I need to load URL on Safari only through cocoa app. If suppose my url is secured I want open url with certificate that is available in keychain access. How to load url on safari using that (available in keychain access) certificates. Now I am selecting manually  while loading url on safari  certificate selection is keep on asking multiple times but it is not loading

Here my code is:

```
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@“http://www.google.com”];

   NSDictionary *theProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:url forKey:@"URL"];
   SafariApplication* sfApp = [SBApplication applicationWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.Safari"];
   SafariDocument *doc = [[[sfApp classForScriptingClass:@“document"] alloc] initWithProperties:theProperties];
   [[sfApp documents] addObject:doc];
```

Thanks :)